# JAVA: managing DataInputStream on multiple threads using same socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, inputstream

So basically I have a main Thread that will accept a socket and create a DataInputStream object to receive data and then pass this Input object to different sub-threads where they will use it to received data and perform different tasks. But that wouldn't work since both threads are using the same object to listen so when a user send something I don't know who will read it..
My thoughts so far:

1- Create some sort of organizer that receives incoming requests and redirects them to responsible thread (I'm not really sure how to do so).

2- When a thread is expecting a sequence of incoming requests (based on time) it has to sleep the other thread so it can take over the inputstream (which I'm not sure if it can be done).

Any other thoughts or how to implement either ones? Thanks!

(in worst cases I'll have to join both threads in one..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you used `ReadWriteLock`, take a depth look of its api and example.
For this cases of join thread u can use `CiclycBarier`

[CiclycBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) and [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)

Hope this help

Comment: I have decided to go with ReentrantLoc, but the thing is, one of the threads is going invoke the client if some condition is true for the client to send data (lets say t1), while the other thread is supposed to be listening for client request (t2). In the this condition t1 will check if lock is not acquired and then try to read from socket, where t2 will run later, acquire lock and starts communication, but when t1 gets back, its already listening, where it should stop.

Comment: do you mean stop all the process of listen and send data or just 1 of them? is it for permanet or just for several time?
Did you design this thread management using `ExecutorService`?
If not, I recommend you to use it, and to stop all the process u can invoke `shutDown()` and `awaitTermination()` method.
you should read their [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) too

Comment: The problem was that, when a thread starts listening, it doesn't stop thus keeping the lock, and blocking other threads.
I solved that by using socket timeout for listeners, which isn't beautiful but works fine.. Thanks

Comment: Like i said in my answer, you have to use `ReadWriteLock` this class design to manage service using 2 separate `Lock` which are `ReadLock` and `WriteLock`. You design 2 service just by 1 `Lock` of course it will cause deadlock. Java have provide such a beautiful API, you should try it or you will regret it :P

Answer (score 2):

I would rather go with option 1. But you shouldn't pass the data input stream to other objects. Rather I suggest that it is the responsibility of one object to extract data from the data input stream. The extracted data can then be passed to another object, which is responsible for processing it. For processing the data you should have a look at the strategy pattern.

Also I think your use of threads is forcing too much coupling by making each thread responsible for one thing. You shouldn't be concerned with that. Instead you should have an [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html). For each accepted socket, you create a task that is passed to the executor. The task itself is extracting the data from the socket via the data input stream and creates another task for processing the data. This task is then again dispatched to the executor. This way you make you application more testable, because you don't necessarily depend on multiple threads.